# Counting pairs of rows in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have this kind of Data Frame:

```
id  type
1   a
1   b
2   b
2   a
3   c
3   b
```

(Each ID has only 2 rows for sure)

I'd like to count the number of each pair, when a pair is the two types per ID.
I mean, to get that result for the previous table:

```
pair  count
(a, b)   2
(b, c)   1
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `frozenset` to have hashable, unordered objects to pass to `value_counts`:

```
df.groupby('id')['type'].agg(frozenset).value_counts()
```

output:

```
(a, b)    2
(b, c)    1
Name: type, dtype: int64
```

*Note that the objects in the index are `frozenset`. I recommend to keep it this way (and to learn how to use them), but if you really need tuples:*

```
out = df.groupby('id')['type'].agg(frozenset).value_counts()
out.index = out.index.map(tuple)
```

Comment: @Mustafa yes, I personally think it's worth to keep it as frozenset to take advantage of its methods but I'll add a note ;)

Answer (score 2):

You can aggregate all of the elements of one type to a list after sorting

```
pair = df.sort_values('type').groupby('id').agg(tuple)
```

and then group by this new column:

```
print(pair.groupby('type').size())
```

Which gives

```
type
(a, b)    2
(b, c)    1
dtype: int64
```

The sort here ensures that you never have `(b, a)`, this always becomes `(a, b)` so they will always be grouped together. If order matters, remove the sort.